# AI Platform Notebooks unable to Launch terminal

Tags: npm, jupyter, jupyter-lab, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

Getting the following errors when launching Terminal in TF 2.3 image

```
Launcher error
a is not a constructor
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for finding the issue and posting the workaround. wit-widget 1.7.1-alpha.3 was not meant to be exposed as the "latest" package for wit-widget, as it has issues. wit-widget latest tag has been reverted back to 1.7.0.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

wit-widget 1.7.1alpha3

**Workaround:**

SSH into the instance and disable extension:

```
jupyter labextension list
Config option `kernel_spec_manager_class` not recognized by `ListLabExtensionsApp`.
JupyterLab v1.2.16
Known labextensions:
   app dir: /opt/conda/share/jupyter/lab
        @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager v1.1.0  enabled  OK
        @jupyterlab/celltags v0.2.0  enabled  OK
        @jupyterlab/git v0.11.0  enabled  OK
        jupyterlab-plotly v1.5.1  enabled  OK
        jupyterlab_gcpscheduler v1.0.4  enabled  OK
        nbdime-jupyterlab v1.0.0  enabled  OK
        plotlywidget v1.5.1  enabled  OK
        wit-widget v1.7.1-alpha.3 enabled OK

jupyter labextension disable wit-widget 
# Ignore `Config option `kernel_spec_manager_class` not recognized by `DisableLabExtensionsApp` message.

jupyter labextension list (Verify wit-widget is disabled)
service jupyterlab restart
```